# how to return response message with 400 bad request status code from django restframwork?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-jwt

Code in Python Django:

```
if len(error) < 1:
    return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    return Response({"data":error}status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

code in javascript

```
if(response.status===200){
    alert("ok")
}else if(response.status===400){
    alert("not ok")
}
```

It returns the code when it is 200 ok, but returning nothing when it is 400 bad request. In fact, nothing seems replying message except 200_ok code. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: the code is correct but need , in  return Response({"data":error}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST).

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

```
return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data=error)
```

Docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#response-objects

Comment: If this solved your issue, please select the answer as the correct answer so others can easily access the solution.